# How to match a sequence of events in Splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

My SPL expertise are limited. I'm trying to write a search which matches a sequence of events.

I'm working with sysmon logs from a windows machine.

first event is a file creation event where ***Image*** ends with ***dllhost.exe*** and ***TargetFilename*** starts with ***C:\windows\system32***. something like:

`index=sysmon EventID=11 Image="*dllhost.exe" TargetFilename="C:\\windows\\system32\\*"`

next event is an image load event where ***Image*** starts with ***C:\windows\system32*** and ***Signature*** does not start with the keyword ***"Microsoft "***. something like

`index=sysmon EventID=7 Image="C:\\windows\\system32\\*" Signature != "Microsoft *"`

Value of ***TargetFilenam***e in Event 1 must be equal to value of ***ImageLoaded***  field in Event 2.

And Event 2 must occur within 1 minute of Event 1.

I tried inner join, where I join results based on ***TargetFilename*** from Event 1 and ***ImageLoaded***  (renamed) from Event 2, But this solves only first part of the puzzle. I want both events to occur in a sequence i.e. join if Event 2 time is less than 1 minute of Event 1 time.  I don't know how to articulate this with SPL.
Also I'd nice if someone can show me how to do all this with tstats :)

Thanks

Comment: Consider using [`transaction`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.6/SearchReference/Transaction) for temporal grouping.

Comment: I imagine you don't want to use tstats as tstats only looks at the indexed metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `stats` to group items by a field.

First, make a column that you can use for matching.
Make sure the match field is empty for anything you don't want to group.
Then use the stats command to group the events

```
| eval Match=case(EventID==11,TargetFilename,EventID==7,ImageLoaded)
| table Match EventID Image TargetFilename Signature ImageLoaded
| stats list(*) as * by Match
```

Here is a "run anywhere" example that makes the events and the joins them up

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="
EventID Image                 TargetFilename         Signature ImageLoaded
11      dllhost.exe           C:\windows\system32\X  Microsoft IL
9       I                     TF                     S         IL
7       C:\windows\system32\I TF                     Apple     C:\windows\system32\X
"
| multikv forceheader=1 fields EventID Image TargetFilename Signature ImageLoaded

| eval Match=case(EventID==11,TargetFilename,EventID==7,ImageLoaded)
| table Match EventID Image TargetFilename Signature ImageLoaded
| stats list(*) as * by Match
```